# Clickhouse Dictionaries: why CREATE DICTIONARY needs a database?

Tags: clickhouse

The *new* [CREATE DICTIONARY](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/create/dictionary/) idiom in ClickHouse will create the dictionary inside a database:

```
CREATE DICTIONARY [IF NOT EXISTS] [db.]dictionary_name [ON CLUSTER cluster]
```

Dictionaries created by XML file are created as empty-string database:

```
<dictionaries>
  <dictionary>
  <name>rates</name>
  <source>
  ...
</dictionaries>
```

and they generate an entry on system.dictionaries like this:

```
:) select * from system.dictionaries \G
...
Row 4:
──────
database:                    
name:                        rates
```

which is empty-string database, that is understood as a global dictionary that can be referred to without a database prefix.

However, with the `CREATE DICTIONARY` SQL idiom, if `db` is not specified, the DICTIONARY is created in the `default` database, no as a global dictionary:

```
:) CREATE DICTIONARY IF NOT EXISTS rates (...)

:) select * from system.dictionaries \G

Row 2:
──────
database:                    default
name:                        rates
```

Question: Is there a way to create a global dictionary via SQL idiom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DDL dictionary cannot reside in the global scope because it does not exist in terms of DDL.

As I understood, your problem is a backward incompatibility xml-based dictionary and DDL one, so the once way to fix it is to add the database-prefix (for example, if it defines in table schema need to apply [ALTER TABLE MODIFY COLUMN](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/alter/column/#alter_modify-column)-statement).
To make migration painlessly from xml- to DDL-based dictionary need to temporarily host both types of dictionaries (xml and DDL) and switched all consumers one by one to DDL dictionaries.

---

DDL dictionaries are much more maintainable and flexible than xml-based ones, because:

- easy to manage them (add, remove, etc) without touching xml-files
- [ON CLUSTER](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/create/dictionary/#create-dictionary-query)-clause allows doing some actions on all the servers of a specified cluster
- manage access [privileges](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/grant/#grant-privileges)
- starting from [v20.4.2.9, 2020-05-12](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/whats-new/changelog/#clickhouse-release-v20-4-2-9-2020-05-12) dictionary can be efficiently used in JOIN-clause instead of *dictGet* (see [Altinity: Clickhouse Dictionaries Reloaded](https://altinity.com/blog/2020/5/19/clickhouse-dictionaries-reloaded))
- work with it as ordinal tables